# doctrine odm mongo and stored procedure

Tags: mongodb, stored-procedures, doctrine-odm

I have saved a js function into the collection db.system.js that retun a sequenceId
and I want to use it for set the id value in an entity.

I'm trying to use this stored procedure in Doctrine odm for MongoDB like follow:

```
$data=new Application\Entities\Data;
$data->setId("getSequence('campagne')");
$dm->persist($data);
```

but the function is not evaluated and the annotation @Id in the entity Data overwrite the value I set.

It's possible use stored procedure in Doctrine odm and how?

thanks in advance

Gisella

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB's [server-side JavaScript execution](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution) is not the same as a stored procedure.  You can only call this from a JavaScript context that executes on the server (eg. db.eval, $where, map/reduce).

A more typical pattern is to use a counter document and the atomic `$inc` function to increment and obtain IDs.  See: [How to Make an Auto Incrementing Field](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+to+Make+an+Auto+Incrementing+Field).

Comment: Yes, I did it too. I would just knew how call a JS and which was the best way to do that. Thanks Stennie.